# Interviewing Get Fit Guy and Nutrition Diva of Quick and Dirty Tips

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I'm thinking about doing a promotion with [Get Fit Guy](http://getfitguy.quickanddirtytips.com/) and [Nutrition Diva](http://nutritiondiva.quickanddirtytips.com/) of the [Quick and Dirty Tips](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/) network. The promotion would involve mentions in their podcasts and newsletters as well as on Facebook and twitter. I think a great way to get their readers to come check out our site would be to interview them beforehand and write it up on our blog. We're doing a similar thing with [Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/) over on English.SE (here is a [meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/what-are-we-going-to-ask-grammar-girl) about it).

What do you think of this idea? Would anybody be willing to help conduct the interview and write up the blog post?